# Symfony2 service DI doesn't resolve my constructor parameters

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2 application, I create a listener to watch Doctrine events.

This is my listener class:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class ProductListener
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function postPersist(Product $product, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

I want to inject in the constructor the symfony DI container. So I configure my services.xml like that :

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="doctrine.listener.product_listner.class">JDecool\Bundle\MyBundle\Listener\ProductListener</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="doctrine.listener.product_listner" class="%doctrine.listener.product_listner.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="postPersist" />
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

The configuration looks like OK because I don't have any error. But when my listner catch an event, the constructor dependency isn't resolve and I have this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for JDecool\Bundle\MyBundle\Listener\ProductListener::__construct()
```

I don't understand why the dependency can't be resolve.
My Listener is register by an *EntityListeners* annotation in my entity.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This: "My Listener is register by an EntityListeners annotation in my entity." is confusing.  The service doctrine.event_listener tag is all you need.  Read here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html I think you are mixing up lifecycle callbacks with lifecycle events listeners.  Also read here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: Yes you're right ! I have made a confusion between the 2 notions. I remove the annotation and all works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jérémy please answer your question on by yourself with the solution and accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You should also refactor your listener and only inject the services it actually needs.  Not the complete container.

Comment: @Cerad, yes i did ! The code sample was only for example :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Cerad says, there is a confusion between EntityListeners annotation and the listener I've registered.

If I remove ethe EntityListeners annotation, it's work perfectly !

Comment: What version of PHP do you use?